# Is it possible to order mysql records before grouping them?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table for users addresses, they can have as many addresses recorded as they like, but they can specify their default address if they want to. The table structure looks like this:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
| UserId | Address | IsDefault |
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

For each user 1 of the address fields can set IsDefault to a 1, all others will be 0, but not every user will set a default address. What I'm trying to do is select one address row for each user, if they have a default address set then it should be that row, otherwise it should be the first entry it finds (the first address they entered).

The query I have is:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses GROUP BY UserId ORDER BY IsDefault DESC
```

But it doesn't seem to order the records before grouping them. How can I get either the record where IsDefault is 1, or the first record for each User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
userid, 
address,
isdefault
FROM addresses
where isdefault = 1
union
SELECT 
userid, 
address,
isdefault
FROM addresses
where userid not in (select userid from addresses where isdefault = 1)
group by userid 
order by address desc
```

You can use `union` for this.

Comment: This throws up an error - `#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: i removed `limit 1` can you try this?

Comment: Never mind, it's because I copied and pasted in the select statement for `not in` and forgot to change * to userId. This worked great thank you.